# Changing agi parameters before calling the script

Tags: asterisk, agi

I was wondering: is there a way to change the values of the agi parameters before calling the script?

In particular, I need to change the `agi_channel` to a custom value.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

CHANNEL(name) variable is read-only, so you can't change it.

However you can write agi proxy, i.e script which will look STD input, replace agi_channel value, all other info just send to other script(original agi), output from original agi send to asterisk.

You also can send custom param to agi script.